# Use case statement in this SQL statement with UNPIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
FDD, 
MAUTO,
MMAN
FROM MyTable) T
UNPIVOT ( Value FOR N IN (MAUTO, MMAN)) P
```

The query returns the following, which is *almost* what I'm looking for:

```
FDD    Value    N
121A   0        MAUTO
121A   20       MMAN
121B   10       MMAN
121C   43       MAUTO
121D   30       MAUTO
```

How can I use the `case` statement so that, instead of returning *MAUTO* or *MMAN*, it returns *0* (if *MAUTO*) and *1* (if *MMAN*).

The table looks like the following:

```
FDD    MAUTO    MMAN
121A   0        20
```

If there's a better way of doing this, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  FDD,
        Value,
        CASE 
            WHEN N = 'MAUTO' THEN 0
            WHEN N = 'MMAN' THEN 1
        END N
FROM (  SELECT  FDD, 
                MAUTO,
                MMAN
        FROM MyTable) T
UNPIVOT ( Value FOR N IN (MAUTO, MMAN)) P;
```

But, a simpler way would be:

```
SELECT  FDD,
        MAUTO as Value,
        0 N
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  FDD,
        MMAN as Value,
        1 N
FROM MyTableM;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in neither query I can see the actual value, which is the value in columns MAUTO or MMAN.

Comment: @rbhatup did you try them?, because the second is directly using the columns `MAUTO` and `MMAN`, so it can't be that you don't get those values

Comment: Sorry about that, I did try both of them and the 2nd one works, but I prefer the statement that uses the case statement.

Comment: @rbhatup I just updated my answer, so now you have the value with the first one too

Answer (score 0):

I would use CROSS APPLY  with VALUES instead of unpivot. It generally performs better and is much simpler to use.

```
SELECT FDD,T.Value,T.N
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
    (MAUTO,0)
    ,(MMAN,1)
) AS T (Value,N)
```